# Calculus: $\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x^4-3x^2-x+1}{x^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Help with the following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x^4-3x^2-x+1}{x^3+1}$$

Plz solve step by step.

Comment: You have to say what you tried.

Comment: Please add more context to the question, such as what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: if you plug in $x=-1$, you get $0/0$, which means that you should be able to factor $(x+1)$ out of the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you factor the numerator you get $$(x+1)(x^3-x^2-2x+1)$$
When you factor the denominator you get $$(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

From then on, you can just check for $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(t-1\right)^4-3\left(t-1\right)^2-\left(t-1\right)+1}{\left(t-1\right)^3+1}\right) =\lim _{t\to \:0}\left(\frac{t^3+3t-4t^2+1}{t^2-3t+3}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule):
$$\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{x^4-3x^2-x+1}{x^3+1}=\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^4-3x^2-x+1)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+1)}$$
Evaluating the derivatives gives:
$$\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{4x^3-6x-1}{3x^2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Your method is certainly the fastest, for this type of limit